# Incompatible types : Int cannot be converted to "class" data type

Tags: java

I'm trying to insert value to a List using loop for, but this list data type is a class which have constructor in it.
Here is my code :

```
List<Edge> edge= Arrays.asList();
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        System.out.println("insert first vertex that connected to edge : ");
        x=key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("insert second vertex that connected to edge : ");
        y=key.nextInt();
        edge.add(x,y);
    }
```

And the error message on line `edge.add(x,y)` it says :

`Incompatible data types : int cannot be converted to Edge`

Here is the Edge Class :

```
public class Edge{
    int source, destination;
    public Edge(int source, int destination){
        this.source=source;
        this.destination=destination;
    }
}
```

What should i change? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `edge.add(x,y)` to `edge.add(new Edge(x,y))` should help. The list `edge` expects an Object of class `Edge`, while two ints are being passed, causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

`edge` is referring to the list of edges.

So `edge.add(__n)` means to add a new
Edge `__n` in the the list of edges `edge`.

You need to do:

```
Edge new_edge = new Edge(x, y)
edge.add(new_edge)
```

Also it may be better to rename the list to something like
`edge_list`  or `edges`